# Get week range of current month in Android

Tags: java, android, date, mpandroidchart, android-date

I would like to show the week range in the MPAndroidChart Graph. For example in February month I would like to show the xAxis label value like 1-4, 5-11, 12- 18, 19-25, 26-28. Here 1-4 comes from the 1st week of February where previous month dates also availble. But I need only current month days. However I am getting all the dates in the week.

```
 public List<String> getWeeksInCurrentMonth() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);

    List<String> weekRanges = new ArrayList<>();

    while (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month) {
        int week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        if (dayOfWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY || cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
            int startDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - (dayOfWeek - 1);
            int endDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + (7 - dayOfWeek);

            if (endDay > cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
                endDay = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            }

            if (startDay <= endDay && startDay <= cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
                weekRanges.add(String.format("%d-%d", startDay, endDay));
            }
        }

        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    }

    System.out.println(weekRanges);
    return weekRanges;

 }
```

Observed output when run in US locale:

> [5-11, 12-18, 19-25, 26-28, 26-28]

It seems that the first week is missing.

Someone please shed some light here, to acheive the week range with only current month date.

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: How *exactly* do you define a week? Perhaps the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) way? Or a localized way? If so, what locale?

Comment: Consider not using `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed, cumbersome to work with and long outdated. Use `LocalDate` and `WeekFields` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). The modern API is so much nicer to work with. If for older Android, than through [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table).

Comment: [Here is the way I would do it using java.time](https://rextester.com/SEFWW74353). The code has approximately the same length as yours, but I find it much clearer to read and debug than anything you can write with the old-fashioned `Calendar` class.

Comment: I am using date-time and calendar things because we are still supporting some older android versions. By the way, I have made a little modification to my code and it worked as expected. Will post it as an answer.@BasilBourque @Ole V.V

Comment: Possibly repeating myself, when developing for older Android versions, use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) to access Java 8 and later APIs. Follow the link for how.

Answer (score 3):

To get the week ranges with only current month dates, you can modify the logic in your getWeeksInCurrentMonth() method to take the current month into account and exclude any dates from previous or next months. Here's an updated implementation that should achieve the desired behavior:

```
public List<String> getWeeksInCurrentMonth() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int currentYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

    List<String> weekRanges = new ArrayList<>();

    while (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == currentMonth) {
        int week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        // Only consider days in the current month
        if (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == currentMonth && cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) == currentYear) {
            int startDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int endDay = startDay + (7 - dayOfWeek);

            if (endDay > cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
                endDay = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            }

            weekRanges.add(String.format("%d-%d", startDay, endDay));
        }

        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7 - dayOfWeek + 1);
    }

    System.out.println(weekRanges);
    return weekRanges;
}
```

Comment: What if we need to get the previous month's week ranges same like current month ?      int currentMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH - 1); will work? @whoami

Comment: @Mac_Play No, it will not. It's not so simple with the old `Calendar` class.